# Howto enforce type safety of objects created with spread operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I was surprised that I can create a new object based on existing object and substitute a property with a new value of the wrong type, without any warning.

Example:

```
interface Foo {
  name: string,
  x: number
}

function f(p: Foo, k: keyof Foo, v: string): Foo {
 return {
     ...p,
     [k]: v,
 }
}

const p: Foo = {
  name: 'foo1',
  x: 1
}

console.log(f(p, 'name', '2'));
console.log(f(p, 'x', '2'));    // Incorrect, x changed to string, 
                                // but no warning from the compiler
```

My question is: Is there a way I can instruct TS compiler to flag a warning on the code above?

NOTE:
I realise I can improve my function. The question therefore is focused only on blocking undesired behaviour described above.

```
function f1<K extends keyof Foo>(p: Foo, k: K, v: Foo[K]): Foo {
 return {
     ...p,
     [k]: v,
 }
}

console.log(f1(p, 'name', '2'));
console.log(f1(p, 'x', '2'));    // Flagged by the compiler, as expected
```

Comment: I get an error using your `f1` function; which version of Typescript are you using? [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmANPsgB4UgCuxARtLgL65cMDiARhg6EMhgAeANLIILSCAAmlZAGsIAT3Qw0mAHwAKAA4UM6BtorzbANyuYA2vIC6AShdY8yKAgwDihpfwICADpo8yYIglctDwpHOMFBXAQpamRLIywAXhxmIlIKAHIYTABGcrjWCmqBISyQSnQAGwhIjvQ6UxgLW3LSiDrkcoAmcq8vAG5M7M7u3v7B2ImWcamZ+fiAen3kAEkxdChA8VsWZAQACzgQOgg1ZDAsalon3CA)

Comment: That is by design - I want that warning - x is supposed a number, not a string. However, the original function `f` does not give me any warning, (3.9.2 to answer your question). Edited the question to be more precise about my expectations.